# Soft body hook onto an object?

Tags: animation, physics, soft-body

So I'm trying to achieve an animation in BI where there is a string that is attached at both ends to 2 separate objects. But I can't find anything that lets me take my string and attach it to them. The string is an elongated cylinder that has had a lot of loop cuts in the middle. Help please?

Comment: Okay, this is what I'm looking for, but I dont see the vertex tab while the curve is selected.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean..

Comment: So in the duplicate that you found (thanks for that) the answer includes taking the two end vertices of a curve, and making them into a vertex group. however, I cannot do this, as the toolbar doesn't give me that option.

Comment: You don't need a vertex group for a curve, select a vertex and press `Ctrl H` *hook to new object* to create a empty and hook the selection to it.